# Couldn't match expected type ‘Post’ with actual type ‘Route App’

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-test

I'm trying to use the function `postBody`

```
postBody :: (Yesod site, RedirectUrl site url) => url -> ByteString -> YesodExample site ()
```

from the [Yesod.Test](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-test-1.4.3.1/docs/Yesod-Test.html) package. The documentation says it can be used like this

```
import Data.Aeson
postBody HomeR (encode $ object ["age" .= (1 :: Integer)])
```

However when I tried to use it in my app

```
    describe "Posts" $ do
        it "posts post and returns post" $ do
            postBody PostR (encode $ object [
                "body" .= ("test post" :: Text),
                "title" .= ("test post" :: Text),
                "coverImage" .= ("test post" :: Text),
                "author" .= (0 :: Int)
                ])
            statusIs 200
```

I got the error

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Post’ with actual type ‘Route App’
• In the first argument of ‘postBody’, namely ‘PostR’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
    postBody
      PostR
      (encode
       $ object
           ["body" .= ("test post" :: Text), "title" .= ("test post" :: Text),

            "coverImage" .= ("test post" :: Text), "author" .= (0 :: Int)])
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
    ‘do { postBody
            PostR
            (encode
             $ object
                 ["body" .= ("test post" :: Text), "title" .= ("test post" :: Text),
                  ....]);
          statusIs 200 }’
```

My usage seems to be the same as the example so I can't see why it would fail.

PostR is in the routes file here

`/posts PostR POST`

and the handler for it

```
postPostR :: Handler Value
postPostR = do
    post <- requireJsonBody :: Handler Post
    maybeUserID <- maybeAuthId
    case maybeUserID of
        Just userID -> do
            let post' = post {postAuthor = userID}
            inserted <- runDB $ insertEntity post'
            returnJson inserted
        Nothing -> sendResponseStatus status403 ("Unauthorized" :: Text)
```

Comment: How is your `PostR` defined?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Edited to show the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being that in the posts table there was a column body so Yesod created postBody for this which conflicted with the postBody from Yesod.Test.

The solution is using a qualified import on yesod test

```
import qualified Yesod.Test as T
```